# pd.DataFrame() insert() method does not work

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

If I use insert method that way it gives me an empty object

```
matches_counts = list(map(lambda id : result.loc[(result["id"] == id)]
                    .groupby(["col1", "col2"])                    
                    .size()                    
                    .reset_index(name="count")
                    .insert(1, "newcol", 99)
                    ,ids))
```

Returns
Can smb support?
Thank you very much!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2,4], 'col2': [3, 2,1]})
a = df.groupby(["col1", "col2"]).size().reset_index(name="count").insert(1, "newcol", 99)
```

a returns None

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2,4], 'col2': [3, 2,1]})
a = df.groupby(["col1", "col2"]).size().reset_index(name="count")
a.insert(1, "newcol", 99)
```

works as expected a has newcol with values 99

Comment: becuz `pandas.DataFrame.insert` return None. 
you need to understand **inplace**. inplace return always None, but change variable that already exists.